# Spacing between paragraph of text and itemize list

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, itemize, line-spacing

My code from TeXworks below outputs a paragraph of text followed by an `itemize` list followed by another paragraph of text.  Each paragraph is double-spaced, and the spacing within the text of each item is double-spaced.  However, the spacing between the last line of the first paragraph and the first line of the first item (and the first line of the second paragraph and the last line of the second item) is not equal to the spacing within each paragraph (i.e., double).   How do I make the spacing between a paragraph and an `itemize` list the same as within each paragraph (in this case, double)?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rhead{Name \thepage}
\cfoot{}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent This is My Name\\
This is Something\\
This is Something\\
This is the Date
\pagebreak[0]
\begin{center}
Title
\end{center}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum dignissim arcu, faucibus condimentum ex pulvinar a. Integer vehicula lacus quis molestie vestibulum. Quisque sed ligula in erat faucibus aliquet. Phasellus volutpat luctus nisl nec semper. 
\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum dignissim arcu, faucibus condimentum ex pulvinar a. Integer vehicula lacus quis molestie vestibulum. Quisque sed ligula in erat faucibus aliquet. Phasellus volutpat luctus nisl nec semper. 
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum dignissim arcu, faucibus condimentum ex pulvinar a. Integer vehicula lacus quis molestie vestibulum. Quisque sed ligula in erat faucibus aliquet. Phasellus volutpat luctus nisl nec semper. 
\end{itemize}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum dignissim arcu, faucibus condimentum ex pulvinar a. Integer vehicula lacus quis molestie vestibulum. Quisque sed ligula in erat faucibus aliquet. Phasellus volutpat luctus nisl nec semper. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load `enumitem` and use `[nosep]` as the option.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\noindent This is My Name\\
This is Something\\
This is Something\\
This is the Date
\pagebreak[0]
\begin{center}
Title
\end{center}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum dignissim arcu, faucibus condimentum ex pulvinar a. Integer vehicula lacus quis molestie vestibulum. Quisque sed ligula in erat faucibus aliquet. Phasellus volutpat luctus nisl nec semper.
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum dignissim arcu, faucibus condimentum ex pulvinar a. Integer vehicula lacus quis molestie vestibulum. Quisque sed ligula in erat faucibus aliquet. Phasellus volutpat luctus nisl nec semper.
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum dignissim arcu, faucibus condimentum ex pulvinar a. Integer vehicula lacus quis molestie vestibulum. Quisque sed ligula in erat faucibus aliquet. Phasellus volutpat luctus nisl nec semper.
\end{itemize}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum dignissim arcu, faucibus condimentum ex pulvinar a. Integer vehicula lacus quis molestie vestibulum. Quisque sed ligula in erat faucibus aliquet. Phasellus volutpat luctus nisl nec semper.

\end{document}
```

If you want this to have a global effect, then use

```
\setlist[itemize]{nosep}
```

so that all `itemize` environments will obey this rule.

As an aside, it is considered a bad practice to use forceful linebreaks `\\` inside the document. To get the effect you are looking for, you may use a `tabular` as in the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\noindent 
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
This is My Name\\
This is Something\\
This is Something\\
This is the Date
\end{tabular}
\pagebreak[0]
\begin{center}
Title
\end{center}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum dignissim arcu, faucibus condimentum ex pulvinar a. Integer vehicula lacus quis molestie vestibulum. Quisque sed ligula in erat faucibus aliquet. Phasellus volutpat luctus nisl nec semper.
\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum dignissim arcu, faucibus condimentum ex pulvinar a. Integer vehicula lacus quis molestie vestibulum. Quisque sed ligula in erat faucibus aliquet. Phasellus volutpat luctus nisl nec semper.
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum dignissim arcu, faucibus condimentum ex pulvinar a. Integer vehicula lacus quis molestie vestibulum. Quisque sed ligula in erat faucibus aliquet. Phasellus volutpat luctus nisl nec semper.
\end{itemize}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla bibendum dignissim arcu, faucibus condimentum ex pulvinar a. Integer vehicula lacus quis molestie vestibulum. Quisque sed ligula in erat faucibus aliquet. Phasellus volutpat luctus nisl nec semper.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect!  Thank you so much.  One quick question -- how exactly does tabular help in this case?  When I run the code, it still requires that I use \\ as in "This is my name//".

Comment: @5823573: You can use `\\ ` inside `tabular` but using `\\ ` in the main body is discouraged as it would snatch away the freedom of determining line breaks from LaTeX (which is good at that).

Comment: Oh -- I see!  That clarifies things.  Thanks again.